# How to use instructions frame in our project

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I am new in swift. I am trying to use [Instructions framework](https://github.com/ephread/Instructions#coachmarkbodyview-protocol) in my code .I have successfully implemented  for single button ” view_schedule” with this function

```
@IBOutlet weak var view_schedule: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var use_now: UIButton!

func coachMarksController(_ coachMarksController: CoachMarksController, coachMarkAt index: Int) -> CoachMark {
    return coachMarksController.helper.makeCoachMark(for: view_schedule )
   

}
```

How I can implement  for multiple button in same class i.e., ApplianceDetailVC.swift for my next button “use_now”

Logic that i have implemented for this is

```
var firstInstructionFlag = true
var secondInstructionFlag = false

func coachMarksController(_ coachMarksController: CoachMarksController, coachMarkAt index: Int) -> CoachMark {
    //var poi = UIView()
    if firstInstructionFlag == true
    {
        firstInstructionFlag = false
        secondInstructionFlag = true
        
        return coachMarksController.helper.makeCoachMark(for: view_schedule )
    }
    else if secondInstructionFlag == true
    {
        firstInstructionFlag = false
        secondInstructionFlag = false
        
        return coachMarksController.helper.makeCoachMark(for: use_now )
    }
    return coachMarksController.helper.makeCoachMark(for: use_now )
    
}
```

The problem with this is i am wrongly handling the return type by repeating it for "use_now". Can you handle this return type by providing better logic

Answer (score -1):

```
func coachMarksController(_ coachMarksController: CoachMarksController, coachMarkAt index: Int) -> CoachMark {
    var poi=UIView()
    if firstInstructionFlag == true
    {
        firstInstructionFlag = false
        secondInstructionFlag = true
        poi = view_schedule
        
    }
    else if secondInstructionFlag == true
    {
        firstInstructionFlag = false
        secondInstructionFlag = false
        poi = use_now
    }
    return coachMarksController.helper.makeCoachMark(for:poi )
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't just provide some code, but also explain how it answers the question.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.